# Ordinal probit model tests

Tags: estimation, ordered-probit

I have been reading ordinal probit model however one thing that i am not getting clear is that what standardized tests should be used pre and post estimation of ordinal probit model in STATA?

Thanks for the help. the forum is indeed helpful.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81160/7071) and `spost` suite of command helpfile (particularly `fitstat`).

Comment: There's a user-written command `omodel` for testing the parallel regression assumption.

Comment: the command omodel runs only for probit and logit equations. What other tests should be used for ordinal probit model with both dep and indep variables are on lkert scale.?

Comment: In your other question, I showed an example of `omodel` with an `oprobit`, so your statement that it only works with logit is incorrect. I also showed `fitstat' there. I am not aware of other formal tests.

Comment: Yes i have seen that. The omodel commands run perfectly when  have a probit model but as soon as i replace probit with oprobit and an i before my main indep variable, model doesn't works. I dont think its something with the command rather something from theory back ground is getting missed. We are told that probit and oprobit are almost same, but there can be differences, as in my case.may be i am wrong. confused.

Comment: No one but you has your data and code, so we can't replicate your problem. You don't say what the error/problem is: "model does not work" is very vague. How can you expect anyone to diagnose what's going wrong from this limited information?

Comment: invalid syntax is the eror that i get after i enter my model in STATA.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578397/user-written-command-tpm-generates-invalid-syntax-error-in-stata) for an example of how to ask this sort of question. SE (or Statalist) are a better place for programming questions.